# error in my code for user registration form validation, when the user submits the form

Tags: jquery

Issues in my code for form validation, when the user submits the form
1.after validating the text field also.Still it shows the error message.
2.further I want to know how to validate if all the field is null?

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jquery Validation</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/thk.js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="jsqval" action="action.php" method="post">
        <table width="56%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">

      <tr>
        <td>Name:<input type="text" name="usernmae" value="" id="name" /><br><span id="names" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E-Mail Id:<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" /><br><span id="emails" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Class Location:<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myhome"  value="My Home">My Home
            <input type="checkbox" name="TutorHome"  value="Tutor's Home">Tutor's Home
            <input type="checkbox" name="institute"  value="Institute or Coaching Center">Institute or Coaching Center
            <input type="checkbox" name="online"  value="Online Class">Online Class
            <span id="check" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        a=$('#name');
        if(a.val()=='')
        {
            $('#names').html("Please Enter Your Name");
            a.focus();
            return false;
        } 

        b=$('#email');
        if(b.val()=='')
        {
            $('#emails').html('Please enter your e-mail Address');
            b.focus();
            return false;
        } 


         y = false;
             $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                 if (this.checked) 
                 {
                 y = true;
                 }

                if (y==false) 
                {
                  $('#check').html("Please Check me");

                }
                return false;
             });



    });

});
```

Comment: In your validation methods, you are showing errors if there is a problem. You need to do the same if there is no problem. That means, just add some remove error locig.

Comment: adding to vgsefa point can you write for me if there is no error I am unable to perform these task.what i have to do for working properly for these three fields

Answer (score 0):

Once validate field, don't forget to reset error fields.

such as :

```
$('#names').html("Please Enter Your Name");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9ctasew/2/)

Comment: thanks lot for your valuable answer.my final doubt how to show if all the user field is null when the user hit the submit button.where i have to include the check box  data like. if(a.val()=='' || b.val()=='') I hope you understand where i got struck.

Comment: my sincere thanks to all the stack team.can you tell me why do i want use this one, because everything is now correct.why you suggested this code $('#name').keyup(function(){ if($(this).val() !=''){ $('#names').html(''); } else{$('#names').html('Error for User to act.')} })

Comment: You are welcome. But stack team and commmunity member are different things. Stack team used for the SO company that runs servers etc.

Comment: thank where do i use this code. $('#name').keyup(function(){ if($(this).val() !=''){ $('#names').html(''); } else{$('#names').html('Error for User to act.')} })

Comment: You can use it out side of `('#submit').click(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for update validation message when user update data in a textbox:   `$('#name').keyup(function(){ if($(this).val() !=''){ $('#names').html(''); } else{$('#names').html('Error for User to act.')} })`

Comment: HI I tried with your update code it is not working for me $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
$('#name').keyup(function()
        { 
        if($(this).val() !='')
        { 
        alert('ok');
        $('#names').html('hi'); 
        } 
        else
        {
         $('#names').html('Enter the Name.')
         } 
         }
          });
       });

}); I want to know how to validate if all the field is null? help me

Comment: You need to add the code outside the $('#submit').click event like <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){}; //  here after in the next line add code $('#name').keyup(function(){ if($(this).val() !=''){ $('#names').html(''); } else{$('#names').html('Error for User to act.')} }) </script>

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

Html :

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jquery Validation</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/thk.js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
            .Errorvalidate{
                color:#C3040B;
                border:1px solid #FFADA6;
            }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="jsqval" action="action.php" method="post" id="frm">
        <table width="56%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">

      <tr>
        <td>Name:<input type="text" name="usernmae" value="" id="name" /><br><span id="names" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E-Mail Id:<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" /><br><span id="emails" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="check">Class Location:<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myhome"  value="My Home">My Home
            <input type="checkbox" name="TutorHome"  value="Tutor's Home">Tutor's Home
            <input type="checkbox" name="institute"  value="Institute or Coaching Center">Institute or Coaching Center
            <input type="checkbox" name="online"  value="Online Class">Online Class
            <span id="check" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="submit" id="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

jQuery :

```
function validate(element, mode) {
    var val = element.val();
    switch(mode) {

        case 'empty':
            if($.trim(val) == '') {
                var msg = 'Please fill up this part';
                showError(element, msg);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            break;
        case 'email':
            filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            if(($.trim(val) == '') || !(filter.test(val))) {
                var msg = 'Enter your email correctly';
                showError(element, msg);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            if(element.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length < 1) {
                var msg = 'Please check me';
                showError(element, msg);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            break;  
    }
}
function showError(element, msg) {
    element.removeClass("Errorvalidate");
    element.addClass("Errorvalidate");
    element.after("<div class='Errorvalidate'>"+msg+"</div>");
    element.focus();
    return false;
}
$("*").change(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("Errorvalidate");
});
```

validate your form like this :

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    if((validate($('#name'), 'empty'))===true && (validate($('#email'), 'email'))===true && (validate($('#check'), 'checkbox'))===true) {
            $("form#frm").submit();
    }
}
```